# Karma-Jasmine: How to test $translate.use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**THE SITUATION:**

I am testing the function that allow the user to select a language.
But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: $translate.use is not a function
```

I have seen similar questions in SO and other forums but they are not working for me.

**THE CODE:**

**The configuration:**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {

$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');

$translateProvider.translations('EN', {

    "MY_ACCOUNT":                   "My account",
    "PROJECT_LIST":                 "Project List",
    "SETTINGS":                     "Settings",

});

$translateProvider.translations("IT", {

    "MY_ACCOUNT":                   "Mio account",
    "PROJECT_LIST":                 "Lista progetti",
    "SETTINGS":                     "Impostazioni",

});

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(window.localStorage['language'] || 'EN');

$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage("EN");
```

**The function:**

```
$scope.select_language = function(language)
    {
        window.localStorage['language_code'] = language.code;

        $translate.use(language.code);

        $rootScope.app_language = language.code;
    }
```

**The test:**

```
describe('App tests', function() {

    beforeEach(module('my_app.controllers'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_)
    {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();   
        $translate = {};

        var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope, $translate: $translate });
    }));

    describe('Language tests', function() 
    {
        it('should properly load select_language function', function()
        {
            $scope.select_language({ name: "italiano", url: "img/italy.png", code: "IT"});
            expect($rootScope.app_language).toEqual("IT");
        });
    });
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why I am receiving that error?

How can I properly test $translate.use?

Comment: Where do you inject `$translate`? for me it looks like translate is `{}` which doesn't have `.use` method

Comment: How can I inject it properly?

Comment: same way you inject `$controller` or `$rootScope`

Comment: I have tried, but if I do i get a long list or errors as: Unknown provider: $translateProvider <- $translate.  ---  $scope is not defined--- $rootScope is not defined etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the `$translate` is not your methods and you don't need to test it, then you can return an object with noop method

```
describe('App tests', function() {

beforeEach(module('my_app.controllers'));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_)
{
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();   
    $translate = {
       use: function(){}
    };

    var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope, $translate: $translate });
}));

describe('Language tests', function() 
{
    it('should properly load select_language function', function()
    {
        $scope.select_language({ name: "italiano", url: "img/italy.png", code: "IT"});
        expect($rootScope.app_language).toEqual("IT");
    });
});
```

and if you need to checkout if it's called with correct parameters you can do

```
$translate = {
  use: jasmine.createSpy('$translate.use')
}
```

then you can add it to expectations

```
expect($translate.use).toHaveBeenCalledWith(//language code)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was crashing my head against the wall all the morning to find a solution!

Comment: Been there, did that, happy to help :)